# Series which is in $\ell^p$ but not in $\ell^q$ for all $1\leq q<p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Im looking for an element in $\ell^p$ which is not in $\ell^q$ for all $1\leq q<p$. Does anybody know such a series?

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far, and what your thoughts on the problem are.

Comment: Hint: do $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ first and from there on you can generalize...

Comment: yes thats what i was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1/(n\log^2 n)^{1/p}$.  See Baby Rudin 3.29 re convergence of $\sum 1/(n \log^2 n)$.  Divergence of $\sum 1/(n^{q/p}\log^{2q/p} n)$ should follow from divergence of $\sum 1/n^{q/p+\epsilon}$ for small $\epsilon$ (Baby Rudin 3.28) plus $\lim (\log n)^2/n^\epsilon = 0$ and the comparison test.